# How to format datestring to d, MMM yyyy in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I got this:

```
function parseDate(s)
{
var d = s.split(/\D/);


return new Date(d[2], --d[1], d[0]);
```

with the calendar tag like this:

```
<p:calendar
id="testDate"
styleClass="calendar"
pattern="d MMM, yyyy"
maxlength="10"
onchange="$(this).val(parseDate($(this).val()))"
onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');"
>
<p:watermark for="testDate" value="mm/dd/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

I need to manually parse a date from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'd, MMM yyyy' but with the function above the result is e.g. "Wed, Aug 09 1995 00:00:00" hence could someone help me and tell how how i could change the format so that the string produced would be **d, MMM yyyy**?

I know this should be a very basic task however i am still learning how to code better, therefore all your help and explanations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what exactly would an example date look like in that format ?

Comment: something like `THU, 006 2014`?

Comment: @jhyap - why would one need the month as `006` when there are only 12 months? `MMM` if the abbreviated name of the month, as in `JUN`, `JUL` etc

Comment: that was the format i was asked to do as apparently my company's codes uses that format.. It has to return '9, May 2013' if user enters '09/05/2013' :) @jhyap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy method: use the `.toString()`

```
function parseMyDate(s){

    var dateParts = s.split("/");

    var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

    var dateStrParts = date.toString().split(" ");

    return (date.getDate() + ", " + dateStrParts[1] + " " + dateStrParts[3]);
}

console.log(parseMyDate("09/06/2014"));
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/454ND/1/)

Comment: you should ask this question a month earlier when you get stuck :) Happy coding.

Comment: i was actually trying to find out how to validate my date and i think i trialed and error too many times so the format that my textbox accepts suddenly changed and from reading user's input as 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'mm/dd/yyyy' so i had two big problems to fix. but thanks a lot for your help! one obstacle cleared!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) you can use it to parse your date and format it into whatever format you'd like.