# Validating date in javascript with format d, MMM yyyy

Tags: javascript, validation, date

How can i validate a date input by the user to make sure that the date entered is within the accepted limit 
(e.g. date does not exceed **29** for *feb*, **30** for *apr, jun, and nov* and **31** for *jan, mar, may, jul, aug, oct and dec*) and the months not exceeding **12**?

I have tried to add in conditions and the *&&* simply does not work for me as it always returns an error.

My javascript function is as below:

```
function parseDate(s)
{
var dP = s.split("/");

var date = new Date(dP[2], (dP[1] - 1), dP[0]);

var dateStrParts = date.toString().split(" ");

return (date.getDate() + ", " + dateStrParts[1] + " " + dateStrParts[3]);
}
```

I have an **onchange** currently that will convert the month number to month name from user input and i believe i need to add another function for validation.

Hence how could i write the validation function and how should i add it into my **onchange** event?

There is no submit button for the date.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using `Date.parse()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: If it's in the format `d, MMM yyyy`, why are you splitting it on `/`, there is no `/` in that date format ?

Comment: Hi @adeneo, could you suggest something for me to replace that with? i got that code from another user earlier and it worked fine hence i did not think of altering anything about it :)

Comment: I have no idea, if it works it works, it just seemed strange that you say you have a date in that format, and then you split on /, when the format contains no such character ?

Comment: well, it doesn't affect the way my code works and i guess it's fine to leave it the way it is! :) @adeneo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693298/js-check-for-valid-date-format/28777878#28777878

Answer (score 0):

Use `isNaN` to check `Date.parse()`

```
function parseMyDate(s){

    if (isNaN(Date.parse(s))){
        alert("Your input has no logic at all");
        return;
    }

    var dateParts = s.split("/");

    var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

    var dateStrParts = date.toString().split(" ");

    return (date.getDate() + ", " + dateStrParts[1] + " " + dateStrParts[3]);
}

console.log(parseMyDate("31/02/2014"));
```

**EDIT** [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/tUJLc/1/)

Comment: Hi @jhyap, unfortunately if i entered an invalid date, it'll simply add onto the current day's date and still produce a date, therefore the result will never be 'NaN' so i believe i will have to set a condition for it. However i have no idea why the system does not accept the && operators. Do you have any idea how else a condition can be set? thank you so much you have helped me a lot! you helped me in my other acc but i couldn't log into that yesterday there was some problem with my email.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112958/how-to-format-datestring-to-d-mmm-yyyy-in-javascript

Comment: the second part of that qn you helped me yesterday @jhyap

Comment: I could not see a clue of your problem. I would guess you want to mean is when user enter `31/02/2014` it will prompt error message right?

Comment: yeah but in the textbox and not an alert @jhyap

Comment: You mean, when user key in `31/02/2014` inside a `textbox`. There is another message print somewhere in the browser by saying "you enter a wrong date" ?

Comment: uhm when the user keys in '31/02/2014' the onchange event will activate and return 'Invalid Date'

Comment: `onchange="$(this).val(parseMyDate($(this).val()))"` include my above example with the `Date.parse()`, you mean it wont give you a `NaN` even you the `$(this).val()` is invalid date? You are using a calendar and I doubt you can select `31/2/2014` in the calendar. Your user input is a selection from calendar or user typing input?

Comment: The user input is both selection from calendar and user typing input. Yeap i included that and it doesn't give me a **Nan** on user typing input. I have no problems with user input selection from calendar. @jhyap

Comment: if i entered, say, `36/06/2014` the results will be `6 Jul, 2014`. @jhyap

Comment: I updated the question with a jsfiddle, it is catching `NaN` with no problem.

Comment: that's weird. do you think it's because of my calendar? because if i entered a date that's beyond the limits of that month, it will simply add it together. For example `36/06/2014` would add up with today's date, `10/06/2014` and produce `06/07/2014`. Is there anyway that i could show you...? perhaps screenshot? @jhyap

Comment: If i entered `31/02/2014` it'll return `3 Mar, 2014` @jhyap

Comment: Yes. You can add screenshoot with reputation more than 10.

Comment: would if/else statements be possible? @jhyap

Comment: the problem is not about if-else, is about it auto correct your input with increment of next following days. Check with your supervisor how does it work and prevent auto-correction if necessary.